# Vc++/c++ Force Include Header Exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, makefile

So I have been developing a project in Linux using makefiles and g++, but now I want to have it run in Windows on Visual Studio. So my project have a special cpp and .h file. Only 1. I configuerd the .h to automatically include that .h file in all cpp files except that special cpp file.However, I can't seem to do so in Visual Studio.

I am basically writing my own vcxproj file, so I looked for configuration settings and I found the Force Include flag in the settings. But I can't seem to find a way to make that exception.

I also tried modifying the .h file so that if it can recognize where it was included from and behave differently through preprocessing instructions like #if and "__FILE__". But I found that "__FILE__" will return the .h either way, not the source.

I ran out of ideas and keywords to search on google. So any ideas or leads?

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit:**

Example code that is working on Linux:

Special.h

```
class Test{
private:
Test() = delete;
Test(const Test&) = delete;
Test(Test&&) = delete;
public:
    void print(const char*);
};
extern TEST t1;
```

Special.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
class Test{    //Singleton Class
private:
Test();    //Note that this line is different from the .h
Test(const Test&) = delete;
Test(Test&&) = delete;
public:
    static Test& getInstance();    //Note that this line is missing from the .h
    void print(const char*);
};
Test::Test(){}
Test& Test::getInstace(){
    static Test inst;
    return return inst;
}
void Test::print(const char* msg){
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
Test t1 = Test::getInstance();
```

Main.cpp

```
int main(){
    t1.print("Hello World!");
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: App-Main

App-Main: Main.o Special.o
    g++ Main.o Special.o
Special.o: Special.cpp
    g++ -c $< $@ -std=c++11
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $< $@ -std=c++11 -include Special.h
```

That's the code which is working in Linux so far. No build error nothing.
The problem if we include the `Special.h` in `Special.cpp`.
For now, please assume there is a reason to not include the .h file in the cpp file.

Comment: A detailed description is good, but not as good as code. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And if you get build errors, can you please show them too?

Comment: Just added an example of a working example. My problem is not a build error, it is a design issue. I am looking for a solution to either make an exception in Visual Studio, or include in the `Special.h` in `Special.cpp` without but it acts as if `Special.h` is empty. If there something that can make the compiler forget something that's declared before. Something like #undef or something. I don't know, I am just guessing wishing right now.

Answer (score 1):

You *define* the class `Test` in *both* the header file and the source file. Remove the class-definition in the source file and keep only the member function implementation.

---

When you ask the pre-processor to `#include` a file, it really includes the actual contents on the place of the `#include` directive.

After pre-processing your file would look something like

```
...
class Test{
public:
    void print(const char*);
};

class Test{
public:
    void print(const char*);
};
void Test::print(const char* msg){
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It can't be done. The class dentition is actually different in a sense but the linker think they are the same. hmmmm okay I will try to modify the example to reflect that.

Comment: @DanMaklen Maybe you want something like [the pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom)?

Comment: @DanMaklen Also, the two classes are really two different classes. Think about what would happen if the classes have different member variables, when the compiler (or you through `new`) allocates instances of the class in the header file the member variables of the class in the source file are unknown, and using the member variables of the class in the source file will lead to undefined behavior, as they might not be allocated or constructed at all. This could be solved by using the pimpl idiom I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: In the point of view of the compiler and the linker this is a valid syntax and it will work normally if the includes are right. What happens is that the compiler does a pass on each cpp file. When it passes on the `Special.cpp` it knows that there is those specific functions that it need. And when it do the pass on the `main.cpp` it knows only about the print function. So `main.cpp` cannot pass even the compilation stage if it tries to construct a new one.
And when the linking comes, it it does find the location of the functions from `main.o` in the `Special.o` so it works correctly.

Comment: @DanMaklen You need to read about the concept of [*trnaslation units*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29). Each source file together with all its included header files is a separate translation unit, and the compiler doesn't actually know anything about any other translation units. All it knows is what it's told in the translation unit it is currently compiling. If the compiler sees a class definition, then that class definition is all it know about, it will not know about other and conflicting class definitions in other translation units.

Comment: @DanMaklen: What you describe (different implementations) violates the One Definition Rule. Not only must the definitions be literally identical, the lookup of names must also match.

Comment: @DanMaklen To continue, if the conflicting class definitions is of different size, then you will have *undefined behavior*, when your code tries to access unallocated memory, or worse memory allocated for something else. And no the linker won't be able to handle it either, as the code is already generated for the different translation units, all it does is resolve external symbols in the object files and libraries you link with, it knows nothing of objects or their sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to #include the "Special.h" everywhere. It has a header guard, of course. Now in the compilation of "Special.cpp", also pass `/D=SPECIAL_H_HEADERGUARD`. The header will still be physically included, but logically skipped.

Of course, the reason you want to do this (intentional ODR violation) is rather dubious, and the actual outcome isn't guaranteed. For instance, Link-Time Code Generation (LTCG) violates your "dumb linker" assumption.